# link click count store to variable in php

Tags: php

I need some help with a link click counter.
I have a text file with links, and a code that randomly extracts one of them and if visitor referer is found in this list, it gets replaced.
I need to store in a variable how many times link extracted from the text was clicked.

```
$usr_ref = parse_url($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]);
$text_url = str_replace("www.", "", $usr_ref[host]);     
$lines = file('test.txt');    
echo str_replace("$text_url", "replaced_link.com", $lines[array_rand($lines)])."<br>";
```

I  am sorry if the question was already asked, i was looking for it, but some topics were removed, others wasnt usefull.